# How to Consume Jersey web service response

Tags: rest, jsp, jakarta-ee, jersey

I have made a Jersey web service using jax and java, it's working when I paste my web service's url in my browser it shows me an xml of my database .

Now I want to consume this xml , I want to be able for exemple to take the path of Image and show it in my main page and take the name and all the other things and make like an instagram feed .

I want to show for every object in xml the image and the other info in a feed.

I apologize if this question sounds stupid but it's my first time

the xml I am getting is a list of objects like this :

```
 <image>
 <category>automobile</category>
 <date>2019-40-08 02:40:18</date>
 <description>lamborghini lp-750sv </description>
 <name>New car</name>
 <PATH>
 C:\Users\ilyas\Desktop\PROJETS\workspace      eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SupPinterest\uploads\automobilelambosv750.jpg
 </PATH>
 <username>ilyas110298</username>
 </image>
```

this is my image.java:

```
 package com.servlet;

 import java.io.Serializable;

 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
 import javax.servlet.http.*;

 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

 @XmlRootElement(name = "image")
 public class image extends HttpServlet implements Serializable {
String name , description , PATH , date , category , username;

public image() {

}
public image(String name, String description, String pATH, String date,                String category, String username) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    PATH = pATH;
    this.date = date;
    this.category = category;
    this.username = username;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public String getPATH() {
    return PATH;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
@XmlElement
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@XmlElement
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
@XmlElement
public void setPATH(String pATH) {
    PATH = pATH;
}
@XmlElement
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
@XmlElement
public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}
@XmlElement
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
} 
}
```

and here is my imageDAO:

```
package com.servlet;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class imageDao {


public List<image> getAllImageList(){
    List<image> imageList = null;
    //boolean st =false;
      try{

     //loading drivers for mysql
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     //creating connection with the database 
         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
                        ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/supdb?            useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","ilyas");
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs =stmt.executeQuery("select * from image");
         imageList = new ArrayList<>();
         while(rs.next()) {
             String name = rs.getString(1);
             String description = rs.getString(2);
             String PATH = rs.getString(3);
             String date = rs.getString(4);
             String category = rs.getString(5);
             String username = rs.getString(6);

             imageList.add(new image (name, description, PATH, date, category, username));

         }
         rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         con.close();

         return imageList;
      }catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

        return imageList;
}
}
```

and finally my imageSERVICE:

```
package com.servlet;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Path("/imageservice")
@XmlRootElement
public class imageService {

imageDao imageDAO = new imageDao();
@GET
@Path("/imageList")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public List<image> diplayImage(){
    return imageDAO.getAllImageList();
}
}
```

I am using eclipse and apache and mysql

When i use an API tester and paste the api url (http://localhost:8080/SupPinterest/image/imageservice/imageList)
I get the error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
```

Comment: Please use Java naming convention. 1) Class names begin with uppercase letters. 2) All caps (e.g. PATH), should only be used for class member constants. and generic class level typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution , the dependencies where wrong

[here is a picture of the dependencies i put in web-inf/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUBut.png)

you just need to install all the dependencies one by one and same version , I deleted all dependencies and I started to run the program get the dependency error and look for the jar until it worked